# make a list item inline when list has list-style-type

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a simple list:

```
<div>Why did the duck cross the road?</div>  <!-- div added for context -->

<ul>
    <li>To get to the other side</li>
    <li class="correct">To prove he's no chicken</li>
    <li>because it was the chicken's day off</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is to highlight the correct answer, so I have the class:

```
.correct
{
    background: rgba(3, 113, 200, 0.2);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jq8DW/)**

The problem is that I want to highlight only the text of the list item, ie I want the correct item to be inline.

But if I add `display:inline` / `display:inline-block` to the .correct class - the `list-style-type` gets mangled.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jq8DW/1/)**

Now, I know that I can add a span element into the markup for the correct item to achieve this like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>To get to the other side</li>
    <li><span class="correct">To prove he's no chicken</span></li>
    <li>because it was the chicken's day off</li>
</ul>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jq8DW/3/)**

..but I was wondering whether I could do this without the extra span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jq8DW/18/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>To get to the other side</li>
    <li class="correct">To prove he's no chickenTo prove he's no chickenTo prove he's no chickenTo prove he's no chickenTo prove he's no chickenTo prove he's no chicken</li>
    <li>because it was the chicken's day off</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.correct {
    display:inline;
    background: rgba(3, 113, 200, 0.2);
}

.correct:before {
   content: "";
   display: list-item;
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Great Danield. Kindly Check broswer compatibility as per you requirement as some times :before pseudo selectors are tricky.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a list style on elements displayed as anything other than `list-item`.

By floating and clearing your list items, though, you can achieve the same thing. Hide the overflow of the `<ul>` to clear floats, then I think you've got what you needed:

```
ul{
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
.correct {
    background: rgba(3, 113, 200, 0.2);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jq8DW/16/)

Comment: +1 thanks, this seems like a good solution, one problem though when there is more than one line of text - the whole last line is highlighed: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jq8DW/17/

Comment: If you want multiple lines, then you'd have to revert to your original idea with the `<span>`s.